# "Restore operation failed due to invalid parameters or format of the parameters is not correct" from Restores.TriggerAsync

Tags: azure-vm

I am using Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup 4.0.1 to restore Azure VM in C#, I received an error on Restores.TriggerAsync:

> "Restore operation failed due to invalid parameters or format of the parameters is not correct"

I tried to find the documentation on how to set the parameters with RestoreRequestResource, I couldn't find anything. Can someone using Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup, help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error for a few days, finally I resolved the issue. For Restores.TriggerAsync API call, the paramter's Properites needs to be set to an IaasVMRestoreRequest instance, which will become the REST API call body.